# PHP handle errors

Tags: php

Using this code with simplehtmldom script (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

```
function file_get_html() {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $args = func_get_args();
    $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    return $dom;
}

$url = 'http://site.com/';
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

How to handle erros on `file_get_html($url)` part? Now, if page doesn't exist, it shows errors in browser window. I prefer to catch them and show my text instead, like:

```
if(some error happened on file_get_html($url)) {
   $errors = true;
} else {
   html = file_get_html($url);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Try putting `try-catch` like this in your function:</strike>

```
try{
    $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    return $dom;
}
catch(Exception $e){
  //echo $e->getMessage();
  throw new Exception('could not load the url');
}
```

**Update:**

Or you can use this function to see if the remote link really exists:

```
function url_exists($url){
    if ((strpos($url, "http")) === false) $url = "http://" . $url;
    if (is_array(@get_headers($url)))
         return true;
    else
         return false;
}
```

Here is how you can use above function:

```
function file_get_html() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    if (url_exists($args)) {
      $dom = new simple_html_dom;
      $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
      return $dom;
    }
    else {
      echo "The url isn't valid";
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell a bit more about catch() part. $e->getMessage() - what does it mean?

Comment: seems it doesn't work, gives an error (like before): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: I think Simple HTML DOM Parser does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: @Ignatz: See this please for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: @Sarfaz This code doesn't work. Because in case of 404, headers also comes as an array. Lars' solutions seems better.

Answer (score 6):

Hi 
You need to check for the 404 Not Found message as there is returned an array in any case.

```
function url_exists($url){
if ((strpos($url, "http")) === false) $url = "http://" . $url;
$headers = @get_headers($url);
//print_r($headers);
if (is_array($headers)){
    //Check for http error here....should add checks for other errors too...
    if(strpos($headers[0], '404 Not Found'))
        return false;
    else
        return true;    
}         
else
    return false;
}
```