# 2 questions about `file_get_html`

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to use `simple_html_dom.php` to do some work.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com');
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) {
echo $element;
}
```

I have 2 problems.

1. How to add a judge if `failed to open stream`: then `echo 'this is not a valid url';`?
2. How to make a judge if there is no `p` tag in `foreach`, then `echo 'Can not find p tag';` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a side-note (maniators answer seems just fine!). My experience with simple_html_dom is that one usually is better off using xpath instead.

Comment: `file_get_html()` returns a valid `Simple_HTML_DOM` object regardless if the file loads/is parsed properly. Therefore, @maniator's answer is incorrect. The error message will never appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.domain.com') or die('this is not a valid url');
$p = $html->find('p');
if(count($p) <=0){
   die('Can not find p tag')
}
foreach($p as $element) {
echo $element;
}
```

Comment: -1: `file_get_html()` returns a valid `Simple_HTML_DOM` object regardless if the file loads/is parsed properly. You'll never actually get your error message.

Comment: you might not get the 1st one, but you will def get the second one

Comment: that is untrue. i have used it in that way many a times. especially when calling mysql_query()...or die(...)

Comment: @ircmaxell: `OR` has a lower precedence than `=`. `=` has a lower precedence than `|`.

Comment: ok so its valid, so it will go through?  so it wont get an error, im not sure why this is a -1?

Answer (score 3):

That's part of the problem with `Simple_HTML_DOM`... `file_get_html()` always return a valid object regardless if the load failed or not. Creating your own instance doesn't help either... There is no actual way of knowing if your file parsed properly or not.

As for finding out if you actually have `<p>` elements in your result:

```
$pTags = $html->find('p');

if(empty($pTags)) {
  echo 'Cannot find p tag';
} else {
  foreach($pTags as $element) {
    echo $element;
  }
}
```

Overall, I would recommend dropping `Simple_HTML_DOM` and migrate your code to [`phpQuery`](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) instead (on a plus side, `phpQuery` doesn't do its own parsing, it is simply a wrapper for PHP's DOMDocument class). The API is more streamlined and allows you to know if parsing succeeded or not.

```
try {
  $html = phpQuery::newDocument($sourceCode);

  $pTags = $html->find('p');

  if(empty($pTags)) {
    echo 'Cannot find p tag';
  } else {
    foreach($pTags as $element) {
      $element = pq($element); // Wrap raw DOMNode in phpQuery object instance;
      echo $element->html();
    }
  }
} catch(Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458697/php-handle-errors

Comment: @JoeSlav: That's a workaround, and if the URL returns data that ISN'T HTML (i.e: Binary file), you'll still end up with an `Simple_HTML_DOM` instance which will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = new Simple_html_dom();
$ipaddrss='write your url here';
$html = file_get_html($ipaddrss);
$anchor=$html->find('dd[class=count]');//you can find the tags with its attributes like 
//shown here
if($anchor) {
    echo $anchor;
} else {
    echo "sorry! no tags found";
}
```