# How to check, the webpage is valid?

Tags: php, parsing

My PHP Code:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$value1 = "http://isitraining.in/$message";
$html = file_get_html($value1);

$rain = $html->find('h1');
$weather = $html->find('h2');
$rains = strip_tags($rain[0]);
weathers = strip_tags($weather[0]);
```

It is working well for valid city name, $message=london;

If it is not a valid city name, if $message=abc;
 It returning like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

My HTML Source:
$message=abc;

```
  <h1>Oops!</h1>
  <h2>No results! There might be something wrong with the city name..</h2>
```

if $message=london;

```
  <h1>No</h1>
  <h2>Conditions for <strong>London, England, United Kingdom</strong><br/>on Fri, 16 Aug 2013 2:18 pm BST: <strong>Mostly Cloudy</strong> (22&deg;C, 70&deg;F)</h2>
```

Comment: If the web site is well done then it returns an error code in the http headers. That is much more reliable to detect than parsing through the dom tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP handle errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458697/php-handle-errors)

Comment: You know your script is basically just scraping a site which is reading a feed ... you could just fetch the data from the Yahoo Weather feed yourself and cut out the middle-man *shrugs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is not because you are setting the variable to abc, it is because the URL doesn't exist. I am assuming that is what you mean when you ask to check if a webpage is valid. You could try getting the headers for the page and if they return a 404 then you can throw an error:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$value1 = "http://isitraining.in/$message";
$file_headers = @get_headers($value1);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo "File was not found!";
} else {
    $html = file_get_html($value1);

    $rain = $html->find('h1');
    $weather = $html->find('h2');
    $rains = strip_tags($rain[0]);
    weathers = strip_tags($weather[0]);

    // Rest of your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if `$html` was an object:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$value1 = "http://isitraining.in/$message";
$html = file_get_html($value1);

if (is_object($html))
{
    $rain = $html->find('h1');
    $weather = $html->find('h2');
    $rains = strip_tags($rain[0]);
    $weathers = strip_tags($weather[0]);
}
else
    echo "No good.";
```